# Degree of a node by geometric random undirected graph

Tags: random-graphs

suppose nodes with radius R are  distributed randomly in Area of size A, then how can we calculate the degree of each node by geometric random graph.

Answer (score 2):

If the nodes are Poisson distributed the degree of a node is Poisson with mean given by the expected number of nodes within range (depending on the density, range $R$ and how close to the boundary).  If instead the nodes have a fixed number and are uniformly distributed, there are small corrections to this.  For more details, try

> > > Mathew Penrose *Random geometric graphs*. Oxford University Press, 2003.
> > >
> > > Mark Walters *Random geometric graphs*, in *Surveys in Combinatorics*, 2011.